# how php script will run in background after a form has been submitted even if log out from a/c

Tags: php, background-process

I am doing a mass mailer project. Everything is going fine but the problem is that I have a form. After submit I am retrieving mass email id from the database (around 3000 emails). I have given 3 sec interval (using the sleep() method) for each email. It will  take around 9000 secs. Users don't want to be stuck in the same page till that php script execution has finished.

How can I run a php script in background even after signing out in widows platform? If the user logs in again one progress bar should be visible. Is there any possibility without using a Cron job?

I need a solution. Can anyone Please help me out for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

To run a process in background, we can use 'wge't command which has many options to use with like(-r, -o, -p)

For your problem you want to run a specific module/url in background so that once you fire it then it should keep working in background so for that you can below command:

wget -o logfile linux.about.com &

For more detail on wget you can refer below link:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/Example-Uses-Of-The-Command-Wget.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain a queue and that will hold your request and that queue should be then used by a Cron Job running in the background. The request should have a flag that can tell user if the cron has been completed or how much percentage is competed.

The emailer should not be run from the web. Make it a cron job.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response . can u plz send me the link of Cron job demo if u have.

Comment: here is a link on cron job tutorial : http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through "CRON JOB". If you are using cPanel you can easily found it. For Other hosting control panels it's called "Timed Schedule". You can google "How to setup cron job".